# COALESCE is not working as expected (mysql)

Tags: mysql, null, coalesce

I am trying to write a breakdown of sales and profit per month, and the coalesce function doesn't work as expected, i.e. doesn't change the NULL by what I would like to.

Here is my code:

```
SELECT  coalesce (extract(month from o.order_date),'Total year') AS mois, 
                sum(op.selling_price * op.quantity) AS 'Monthly sales',
                sum(op.selling_price * op.quantity) - sum(p.buying_price * op.quantity) AS 'Monthly Profit',
                count(r.return_id)
FROM order_products op
JOIN orders o
ON o.order_id = op.order_id
LEFT JOIN returns r
ON r.order_product_id = op.order_product_id 
JOIN products p
ON p.product_id = op.product_id
WHERE extract(year from o.order_date) = '2016'
GROUP BY mois
WITH ROLLUP;
```

When running this code, the last line (rollup) still shows 'NULL' under the column 'mois'.

Any idea about what I could have missed?

I have tried with the function ifnull but I get the same issue.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the query using rollup in a subquery, and use `COALESCE` in the main query.

```
SELECT COALESCE(mois, 'Total year') AS mois, `Monthly sales`, `Monthly Profit`, return_count
FROM (
    SELECT  extract(month from o.order_date) AS mois, 
                    sum(op.selling_price * op.quantity) AS 'Monthly sales',
                    sum(op.selling_price * op.quantity) - sum(p.buying_price * op.quantity) AS 'Monthly Profit',
                    count(r.return_id) AS return_count
    FROM order_products op
    JOIN orders o
    ON o.order_id = op.order_id
    LEFT JOIN returns r
    ON r.order_product_id = op.order_product_id 
    JOIN products p
    ON p.product_id = op.product_id
    WHERE extract(year from o.order_date) = '2016'
    GROUP BY mois
    WITH ROLLUP) AS x
```

Comment: I was trying to find a way to use a subquery but without success.
Your solution works perfectly.
Thanks a lot!